# Read labels from facebook api

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I ant to use the graph API to read some info about public pages.
I can read likes for instance, but I don't understand why I can't have labels:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/labels/

From the Graph API tool explorer :
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

I get an error :

```
{   "error": {
    "message": "(#210) A page access token is required to request this resource.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 210,
    "fbtrace_id": "CLgQRJVq8JV"   } }
```

I tried it with page id 209210135757984, ie for page https://www.facebook.com/CroixRouge/

Comment: What is not clear with that error message?

Comment: reading at the documentation page, I understood that no specific permissions were required to read this data "Reading>Permissions>Other apps : no data"

Comment: That is correct. You just need an access token to tell the API who you are.

Comment: You understood that wrong; it means other "types" of apps have no business accessing this data in the first place. If your app wants to manage anything on a page, such as reading labels, it needs to request `manage_page` permission.

Comment: @CBroe got it. Btw I don't want to manage anything but just read public info using the API

Comment: If it requires a page token to access, then it is not public. (Whether it is publicly visible on the website, is not relevant; UI and API are two different things.)